# Finding an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that it is reducible modulo 2,3 and 5.

Tags: abstract-algebra

The problem is finding an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that it is reducible modulo 2,3 and 5. I can't find anything, any help is appreciated. (Is there some general strategy for doing this?)

Comment: Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: Just look for a simple quadratic.  Try the form $x^2+a$ .

Comment: Have you tried some simple quadratics?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $:$ Take $f(x)=x^4+1.$ Then it is reducible modulo every prime $p.$ But it is irreducible in $\Bbb Z[x].$